# cookie issue with same domain same path but different port

Tags: web-application, webserver, cookies, security-theater

I have two web app running on same host on same path but on different port

http://somedomain.com/

and

https://somedomain.com/

now when I visit first app it serves the cookie say with name `abc`, and now my browser has this `abc`, now if I open another tab and goto app2 (https one), browser sends the cookie `abc` in request (because of same domain, same path) and this app sets the secure flag true because its running on `https`,

so now in my browser `abc` is overriden by `secureflag` = `true`, so if I make request to app1 (which is running on `http`), it doesn't send `abc` because of secure flag and it makes me logout because `abc` is session cookie

what is the secure way to overcome this,

both of the apps are mine so cookie hijacking from another app is not the case

I tried setting app2 at some other path `/foo`

so now its

http://somedomain.com

and

https://somedomain.com/foo

if my browser has the cookie from foo first then everything goes ok, but if I hit app1 first then it still sends the cookie to `/foo`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest and clearest solution is simply using differently named cookies (in addition to setting `secureflag=true` on the secure site cookie), eg. `abc` and `abc_secure`. This also makes development and debugging much much easier.